# SQL-Delete from a table based on a nested query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three tables in a mySQL databse as such:

```
orders: order_sequence_number, contact_id, date_ordered ...

orderdetail: order_sequence_number ...

person: contact_id ...
```

I am trying to delete all rows across the three tables that have a date_ordered value older than two years, however, the date_ordered field only appears in the orders table but the table has links to the other two via the order_sequence_number and contact_id fields.

So, i'd image a bit like this: ...

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE date_ordered BETWEEN X AND Y
```

Then with that record set

```
DELETE FROM orderdetail WHERE orderdetail.order_sequence_number IN (THE ABOVE)
```

Etc for persons table ... but having no luck.

Seems to me like some sort of nested subquery but I am having difficulty understanding how to do such a query and cant get my head around the convoluted nature of it...

Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM orderdetail 
WHERE order_sequence_number IN 
(
    SELECT id 
    FROM orders 
    WHERE date_ordered BETWEEN X AND Y
)
```

Answer (score 2):

thats pretty much what you wrote:

```
DELETE FROM orderdetail WHERE orderdetail.order_sequence_number IN (
    SELECT distinct(order_sequence_number) FROM orders WHERE date_ordered BETWEEN X AND Y
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a big table `orders`, it's better to use [EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

```
DELETE FROM orderdetail od 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL 
               FROM orders o 
               WHERE date_ordered BETWEEN X AND Y
                 and od.order_sequence_number = o.order_sequence_number
             )
```