# MySQL DELETE based on SELECT

Tags: mysql

I am learning SQL. Using MySQL, I am working on a very simple calendar application. SELECT statement below returns a relation with the schedule ID. And I'd like to delete it using the DELETE statement. So I am trying to delete a specific schedule only in `schedule` table. But I am getting a syntax error.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

```
SELECT s.id 
FROM schedule s, meetings m 
WHERE m.date = s.date AND m.time = s.time AND m.id = 1;
// returns 5

DELETE
FROM schedule s, meetings m 
WHERE m.date = s.date AND m.time = s.time AND m.id = 1;  
// trying to delete the row with id=5 but syntax error
```

Please help.

Comment: what error is showing ?

Comment: if you want to delete from 2 table you should to write 2 query, if you want to delete from one table with this condition(as shown above in your question) you should to join tables together and delete from one you want...now tell us you want to delete from which table dude

Comment: I am trying to delete only from schedule table

Comment: @Farrokh He said he wants to delete a schedule.

Comment: @Barmar i know but i want him to work over his question ;-)

Comment: @Farrokh It seemed clear to me: "So I am trying to delete a specific schedule in `schedule` table." He just edited it to add "only".

Comment: @Mrdeveloper Are you sure about that?

Comment: @Farrokh BTW, you *can* delete from multiple tables in one `DELETE` query.

Comment: Check this out this should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/9078987/4878339

Comment: @Barmar, i know that we can delete from multiple table but with join, delete table1,table2 from table1 inner join table2 on some_conditions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the multi-table syntax in the [`DELETE` documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html). The main point is that you have to specify which table(s) you're deleting from after the `DELETE` keyword:

```
DELETE s
FROM schedule AS s
JOIN meetings AS m ON m.date = s.date AND m.time = s.time
WHERE m.id = 1
```